# Where can I find the executed TTL commands in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, ttl

I would like to know the logs of documents removed through TTL indexing. 
I tried using `db.setProfileLevel(2)` and searched the `db.system.profile.find({op:"remove"}).pretty()`, but It returned nothing.

Can you please let me know the location of documents (kind of `IDs` etc) which are automatically removed using the feature TTL MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

From the manual [Expire Data from Collections by Setting TTL](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/tutorial/expire-data/)

> When the TTL thread is active, you will see a delete operation in the
>   output of db.currentOp() or in the data collected by the database
>   profiler.

so try to use `delete` instead od `remove` in the query.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.But, profiler don't even has the records with **op:"delete"**.